# Read and order vector from txt file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

Is a beginner question, but i don't succeed to go out from the error. 
I have a text file with value written like:   `[ 2 3 4 5 1]` 
and another vector where i write the order in which i want reorder the first vector.
So if the order vector is `[ 5 3 2 1 4 ]`
the first vector will become `[ 1 4 3 2 5 ]`. 
The idea was import the file.txt  with np.loadtxt and than:

```
for i in range (5):
    a=int('order[i]')
    b = a
    c = suono[b]
    suono2.write[i] = c
    suono2.save(c)
    emp =  "" 
    suono2.save(emp)
    suono2.close
```

Comment: What do files have anything to do with your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use `numpy`, which is not a *bad* idea if you are working exclusively with numeric arrays, then you can use simple indexing.

You just need to be careful to subtract one since indices begin at 0. This appears to be the cause of your error.

```
import numpy as np
lst= np.loadtxt("vector.txt")
lst = lst.astype(int)
order = np.loadtxt("orderSet.txt")
order = order.astype(int)
# alternative is A = np.array([ 2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
#order = np.array([ 5, 3, 2, 1, 4 ])

res = A[order-1]

print(res)

[1 4 3 2 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have to use `numpy` at all.

With bare python: just rebuild your list using a list comprehension, iterating on the "order" list (minus 1 because python lists start at 0):

```
lst = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
order = [ 5, 3, 2, 1, 4 ]

result = [lst[i-1] for i in order]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getitem**

```
 mylist = range(10)
 indexes= [1,3,5]
 print(list(map(l.__getitem__, indexes)))
```

In Python 3

```
>>> mylist = range(10)
>>> indexes= [1,3,5]
>>> print(list(map(l.__getitem__, indexes))) 
[1, 3, 5]
```